# mv fails with target is not a directory when using date

Tags: command-line, bash

I run this

`sudo mv /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf.{,$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)}`

I get:

> mv: target '/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf.20190517170628' is not a directory

running

`sudo mv /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf.222`

does work though

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
 /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf.{,$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)}
```

This expands to two files, so in total once brace expansion is performed you will have 3 command line parameters to the mv command. Verify that with echo instead of mv

When mv is invoked with 3 or more arguments it will treat all but last as files to be moved and the last item as destination directory where you want to move things.  That is

```
mv file1 file2 directory
```

If your goal is to move only one specific file, the curly brace expansion can be left out and use only  command substitution with date command